# How to save field in database with a value with slashes

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

In Laravel I want to update a field in the database using:

```
$element = ElementValue::find($id)
$element->update(array('value_char' => $new_slug));
```

But the slug is generated from a function and is like `/infobank/item-1`

How do I update the query line for it to save accordingly?

Comment: In `item-1` `1` is the id of the element. Right?

Comment: No, it's just an example. It can me whatever title like `/infobank/item-one` or `/infobank/item-two` adn so on

Comment: Dont really get the question. what you have done is correct, unless you are getting errors. If so can you dump the errors. And what you do mean by **update the query line for it save accordingly**

Comment: Is it saving something but not as expected? Is it saving nothing but returning true? Is it returning an error? More information is needed.

Comment: Never mind guys. It was saving correctly, only it used parents that already had the new slug, so that's why I got `//infobank//infobank//item-1`

Answer (score 0):

It should be saved correctly, if not, you can `urlencode()` to save and `urldecode()` to use.